# How to configure CMake to build multiple projects in a specific order?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a C++ project using CMake. When I generate the Visual Studio files using `cmake -G "Visual Studio 15" . -B .\build`, I can see in the Solution Explorer projects `ALL_BUILD`, `RUN_TESTS`, and `ZERO_CHECK` under CMakePredefinedTargets, `Continuous`, `Experimental`, `Nightly`, and `NightlyMemoryCheck` under CTestDashboardTargets and `MyProject` (which is my actual project).

When I build `MyProject`, I see that Visual Studio first builds the `ZERO_CHECK` project and then `MyProject`. However, I would also like to build `RUN_TESTS` project after `MyProject` because this is where mu unit tests are. Right now, I just right click on my solution and select `RUN_TESTS` to build in Solution Properties. However, is it possible to automatically build and run the project `RUN_TESTS` when ever I build `MyProject`?

My `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
project("MyProject")

add_executable(MyProject test.cpp)

# Configure unit tests
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(MyProject Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(MyProject)
```

In my case, I'm using Catch2 as my test framework. Thanks.

Comment: While the answers will tell you how to do it, may I cast a question mark on the *why*? Running the tests for each build isn't that good an idea. As our project grows, tests will accumulate, until they will take up considerable time. You will usually end up wanting to run a *specific* test only, if even that much, on each build, reserving "full test suite" for pre-commit runs.

Comment: Sure, I didn't think of it much at the time I posted the qn. I guess I might want to do it during a release build or a build pipeline. But thanks for your advice, it's true.

Comment: @swdon There are some examples for running *individual* tests, rather than the entire suite, in [this](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-September/046218.html) thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that could work would be a `POST_BUILD` event in the form of [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html). This example "builds" the `RUN_TESTS` target (which actually runs the tests) after the `MyProject` target is built:

```
# Run the tests after building target.
add_custom_command(TARGET MyProject
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target RUN_TESTS
)
```

Although a bit dated, here is a [thread](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2011-September/046218.html) providing some additional examples for running *individual* tests upon building the project.